# RewriteCond backreference not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, backreference

If I go to `http://www.example.com` I want it to stay there, which is working fine.
If I go to `http://bar.example.com` it redirects to `http://www..com`, which is wrong
I **want** it to go to `http://www.example.com` given the backreference in the `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.(example).com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%1.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Ubuntu 8.04
Package: apache2-mpm-prefork
Architecture: i386
Version: 2.2.8-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negated patterns have no match and thus you cannot reference a group of that non-existing match.

But try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ahh negated pattern. It all makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your condition does not match bar.mysite.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.(mysite).com [NC]
```

You need to change it to match in order to get the backreference working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^[^\.]+\.(mysite)\.com [NC]
```